# Grabbing all items from a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
    var mockData = {
        eventInfo: {
            Title: "Adam",
            Date: "10/06/2016"
        },
        eventInfo: {
            Title: "Red",
            Date: "14/06/2016"
        },
        eventInfo: {
            Title: "Connor",
            Date: "15/06/2015"
        }
    };
```

I have my mock data here which is a JavaScript object.

When I try to `console.log` the values/value I get the last one all the time.

So `console.log(mockData.eventInfo);` gives me back `Object {Title: "Connor", Date: "15/06/2015"}`.

And if I do `console.log(mockData.eventInfo.Name;` I always get back the last the last item in my object.

How can I get out all items in the object, then do my logic with it from there.

Comment: you cant have the same key for each value, you need a different key.

Comment: yes you could make mockData an array of objects, then traverse them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript objects are based on key value pairs. That means that each key has to be unique. In your case, you use the 'eventInfo' key several times. Instead, try to change the structure to something like this:

```
var mockData = {
    eventInfo :[
      {
       Title: "Adam",
       Date: "10/06/2016"           
      },
      {
       Title: "Red",
       Date: "14/06/2016"           
      },
      {
       Title: "Connor",
       Date: "15/06/2015"           
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is an object literal, not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Each object overrides the previous one since they are declared in the same object.

You can easily modify the structure so that each object is in an array instead:

```
var mockData = {
    eventInfo: [
        {
            Title: "Adam",
            Date: "10/06/2016"
        },
        {
            Title: "Red",
            Date: "14/06/2016"
        },
        {
            Title: "Connor",
            Date: "15/06/2015"
        }
    ]
};
```

Now, you can make references to each one via:

```
console.log(mockData.eventInfo[0].Title);  // Adam
```

And of course, you can iterate over them in loops:

```
mockData.eventInfo.forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can't have multiple keys with the same name. Consider an array

```
var mockData = {
    eventInfo: [
    {
        Title: "Adam",
        Date: "10/06/2016"
    },
    {
        Title: "Red",
        Date: "14/06/2016"
    },
    {
        Title: "Connor",
        Date: "15/06/2015"
    }]
};
```

Then you can access everything as mockData.eventInfo[0], mockData.eventInfo[1], ect. It also makes it easy to loop through these.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript object cannot have duplicate keys.

[*The names within an object SHOULD be unique*](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

Here is a small snippet to iterate over object and retrieve it's value

```
var mockData = {
        eventInfo: {
            Title: "Adam",
            Date: "10/06/2016"
        }
    };

var m = (mockData.eventInfo) // mockData is object contains other object
//Use for..in loop only iterates over enumerable properties
for(var prop in m){ 
document.write('<pre>'+m[prop]+'</pre>')
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/8ew4ke2r/)

Answer (score 0):

keys in an object are unique, you cannot have two exact key names within the same object.

you are calling the setter on the object each time you write a new key in the object literal. writing the same object key twice will cause two writes on the same key, hence the last one will always win since it is the last one written on the same key.

What you need to do is group them inside an array as they have the same name.